# Oracle package replace is stuck

Tags: oracle, package, locking

I have this DATA_CAPTURING package I am trying to replace the package body.
The package is called by a scheduled job every 15 minutes. The job can take longer than 15 minutes.
I believe this has to do with locks being held on the package.
I have the following SQL to find potential locks:

```
SELECT s.sid,
   s.SERIAL#,
   s.STATUS,
   s.STATE,
   s.username,
   l.lock_type,
   l.mode_held,
   l.mode_requested,
   l.lock_id1
FROM   dba_lock_internal l,
   v$session s
WHERE s.sid = l.session_id
AND UPPER(l.lock_id1) LIKE '%DATA_CAPTURING%'
;
```

This is the output:

```
12  223 ACTIVE  WAITED SHORT TIME   XXX Cursor Definition Lock  Null    None    SELECT s.sid,        s.SERIAL#,        s.STATUS,        s.STATE,        s.username,        l.lock_type,        l.mode_held,        l.mode_requested,        l.lock_id1     FROM   dba_lock_internal l,        v$session s     WHERE s.sid = l.session_id     AND UPPER(l.lock_id1) LIKE '%DATA_CAPTURING%'
12  223 ACTIVE  WAITED SHORT TIME   XXX Cursor Definition Lock  Null    None    SELECT s.sid,        s.SERIAL#,        s.STATUS,        s.STATE,        s.username,        l.lock_type,        l.mode_held,        l.mode_requested,        l.lock_id1     FROM   dba_lock_internal l,        v$session s     WHERE s.sid = l.session_id     AND UPPER(l.lock_id1) LIKE '%DATA_CAPTURING%'
15  105 KILLED  WAITING XXX Cursor Definition Lock  Null    None    call XXX.DATA_CAPTURING.RUN_EXTRACTION (  )
15  105 KILLED  WAITING XXX Cursor Definition Lock  Null    None    call XXX.DATA_CAPTURING.RUN_EXTRACTION (  )
15  105 KILLED  WAITING XXX Table/Procedure/Type Definition Lock    Null    None    XXX.DATA_CAPTURING
15  105 KILLED  WAITING XXX Body Definition Lock    Null    None    XXX.DATA_CAPTURING
203 489 ACTIVE  WAITING XXX Body Definition Lock    Exclusive   None    XXX.DATA_CAPTURING
15  105 KILLED  WAITING XXX Table/Procedure/Type Definition Pin Share   None    XXX.DATA_CAPTURING
203 489 ACTIVE  WAITING XXX Body Definition Pin None    Exclusive   XXX.DATA_CAPTURING
15  105 KILLED  WAITING XXX Body Definition Pin Share   None    XXX.DATA_CAPTURING
```

I tried to kill the session 15,105 but as you can see its not gone yet.
For killing, I used `alter system kill session 'SID,SERIAL#';`

Meanwhile, my database package replace script received a timeout:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY            "DATA_CAPTURING" AS
ERROR at line 1:    
ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object
```

Is there anything else I can do except waiting for that session to kill itself, or restarting the database?

I solved a very similar question with a restart, but I am not happy with this kind of solution.

Comment: There's probably a better solution about replacing a package body, but if you really need to kill a session without waiting for its transaction to finish, do `alter system disconnect session 'SID,SERIAL#' immediate;` The transaction will be rolled back. In some cases you can also kill the OS process, see https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/killing-oracle-sessions

Comment: Can you suspend the schedule and wait for all running jobs to complete, reload the package, then restart the schedule? (This sounds like something that would normally be done in a maintenance window anyway, when nothing would be running.)

Comment: Suspending the schedule sounds good. I see I can do it with `exec dbms_scheduler.disable(‘RUN_EXTRACTION_SIRIUS_1’);` and check the disablement with `select job_name, enabled from DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS;`

Comment: I also had to issue `exec DBMS_SCHEDULER.STOP_JOB ( job_name => 'RUN_EXTRACTION_SIRIUS_1', force => true);` twice to stop the job being run.

Comment: If that worked and you were able to replace the package body, it would probably be worth you writing up all the steps you had to take as an answer? Including re-enabling the schedule I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution:

```
exec dbms_scheduler.disable(‘RUN_EXTRACTION_SIRIUS_1’);
```

This will give an error message about the job currently running.
So I issued the following command:

```
exec DBMS_SCHEDULER.STOP_JOB ( job_name => 'RUN_EXTRACTION_SIRIUS_1', force => true);
```

However now the "disable" command still gave an error message. Maybe because the scheduler started a new job right away. So issued the "stop_job" command again.
After that, the "disable" command worked.

I then was able to run the database upgrade script to replace the package body of DATA_CAPTURING.

Finally I issued the command to re-enable the job:

```
dbms_scheduler.enable(‘RUN_EXTRACTION_SIRIUS_1’);
```